# object["#"] is defined AND undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some json files and wanted to save them as an object in a bigger object, but when I write "objects["#"]" it gives an error because it's undefined, but if I where to write it in the console... it is defined?

I tried JSON.stringify and "\"#\"" neither of which worked

```js
window.objects = {}
fs.readdir("default_objects", (err, files) => {
  for (file of files) {
    if (file == ".json") objects[" "] = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('default_objects/.json', 'utf8'))
    else if (file.match(new RegExp('.*\.json')) && file == file.match(new RegExp('.*\.json'))[0]) objects[`${file.replace('.json','')}`] = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`default_objects/${file}`, 'utf8'))
  }
})
console.log(objects["#"])
//undefined even though in the default_objects folder there is a #.json file
```

It should work I see no reason why not. It says undefined but it should be the object in the json file, but it works in the windows console?(when I type objects["#"] and press enter it gives the proper output) I'm using electron by the way.
Update: I tried just logging the result in the terminal and it got undefined too? Update: I tried console.logging it in the call back for the fs.readdir call and it worked but the value doesn't update outside of the callback?

Comment: Please be specific, when there's an error message, then tell us the exact message, and if the console logs `undefined`, then say that it is a logged value (which is not an error). Debuggers don't speak ...

Comment: + `fs.readdir` is asynchronous, and you're trying to read objects before they are added to the object. Put the logging inside of the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Use fs.readdirSync instead. fs.readdirSync will provide a array of files which will be processed BEFORE running other code